# Formalizing intuition about distances in $\mathbb{R}$ using inequalities

Tags: real-analysis

I'm solving a proof in my analysis text and the final step boils down to solving the following problem. Say I have two points $a \neq b$ both in $\mathbb{R}$. So let $d = |a-b| > 0$. Now let $a',b' \in \mathbb{R}$ be any two points such that $|a' - a| < d/4$ and $|b'-b| < d/4$. I want to prove that $|a'-b'| > d/2$. This is very intuitive when drawn on paper but how do I reach this conclusion using inequality manipulations?

Answer (score 1):

Assume WLOG that $a<b$. Since $|a-a'|<d/4$, it follows that $a'\in(a-\frac{d}{4},a+\frac{d}{4}):=I_{1}$. Similarly, $b'\in(b-\frac{d}{4}, b+\frac{d}{4}):=I_{2}$. Then, $a'<a+\frac{d}{4}$ and $b'>b-\frac{d}{4}$. Since $|a-b|=d$, we have $I_{1}\cap I_{2}=\emptyset$, and, moreover, $I_{1}$ lies entirely to the left of $I_{2}$; that is $a+\frac{d}{4}<b-\frac{d}{4}$. Hence, 
$$
|a'-b'|=b'-a'>\left(b-\frac{d}{4}\right)-\left(a+\frac{d}{4}\right)=b-a-\frac{d}{2}=d-\frac{d}{2}=\frac{d}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$d=|a-b|=|(a-a')+(a'-b')+(b'-b)|\leq$$ $$\leq |a-a'|+|a'-b'|+|b'-b|<$$ $$<d/4+|a'-b'|+d/4=d/2+|a'-b'|\implies$$ $$\implies d<d/2+|a'-b'|\implies d/2<|a'-b'|.$$